# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.krish.recreatemybank.Models.User.get_id()' on a null object reference(Async Task)

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I am creating a banking app and am using an AsyncTask to fetch all the transactions the user has made.

Here, I am just executing the async task, but am getting a null pointer exception for some reason:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.krish.recreatemybank.Models.User.get_id()' on a null object reference
```

And this is my utils code:

```
Utils utils = new Utils(this);
        User user = utils.isUserLoggedIn();
        Log.d("user_id", user.get_id()+"");
        getTransactions = new GetTransactions();
        getTransactions.execute(user.get_id());
```

The null pointer exception occurs on the line `.execute`.

These are my two Util methods:

```
public void addUserToSharedPreferences(User user){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("logged_in_user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        editor.putString("user", gson.toJson(user));

        editor.apply();
    }

    public User isUserLoggedIn(){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("logged_in_user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<User>(){}.getType();

        User user = gson.fromJson(sharedPreferences.getString("user", null), type);
        return user;
    }
```

...and then I add the user to the shared preferences after they register:

```
utils.addUserToSharedPreferences(user);
```

Also, I've tried logging the user many times, and the user is ***not*** null.

**What may be going wrong here?**

Full stack trace:

```
2021-05-25 19:14:32.106 5575-5604/com.krish.recreatemybank E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.krish.recreatemybank, PID: 5575
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.krish.recreatemybank.Models.User.get_id()' on a null object reference
        at com.krish.recreatemybank.HelperClasses.DatabaseHelper.addSampleTransaction(DatabaseHelper.java:67)
        at com.krish.recreatemybank.HelperClasses.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:60)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:411)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:340)
        at com.krish.recreatemybank.Auth.RegisterActivity$DoesUserExist.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:73)
        at com.krish.recreatemybank.Auth.RegisterActivity$DoesUserExist.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:68)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Thanks!

Code for async task:

public class GetTransactions extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ArrayList>{

```
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Transaction> doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        try{
            SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.query("transactions", null, "user_id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(integers[0])}, null, null, null);

            if(cursor != null){
                if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

                    ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(int i = 0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++){
                        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
                        transaction.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
                        transaction.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")));
                        transaction.setPrice(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("amount")));
                        transaction.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
                        transaction.setTransactionId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));

                        transactions.add(transaction);
                        cursor.moveToNext();

                        Log.d("transactions", String.valueOf(transactions));
                    }

                    cursor.close();
                    db.close();
                    return transactions;


                }else{
                    cursor.close();
                    db.close();
                    return null;
                }
            }else{
                db.close();
                return null;
            }

        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Transaction> transactions) {
        super.onPostExecute(transactions);

        if(transactions != null){
            initAdapter(transactions);

            Log.d("transactions", "Sucess!");
        }else{
            Log.d("transactions", "Failure!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code for the async task. Also does the Log.d show the user's ID?

Comment: Hi, I don't know why, but my logs aren't even showing up, even though I know the code is running. And even in the working version of the app, nothing is logging. I've shut down Android Studio, re-opened it, nothing changes. I've solved the error, but the recycler view still isn't showing the transaction

Comment: I added the code for the async tasks as well.

Comment: Im pretty sure the userID is returning null, Try Log.e("userID",user.get_id()) . This will show the log in red, will be easier to find. Alternatively there is a search function inside the console, so just search userID. @codingChamp

Comment: Hi, I fixed the log error and userId isn't null. It logged 1. I also fixed the crashing error, but the problem is--the recycler view still isn't displaying the transactions

Comment: Currently, I'm just adding a test transaction like this: `private void addTestTransaction(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("_id",0);
        values.put("amount", 10.5);
        values.put("date", "2021-5-04");
        values.put("type", "shopping");
        values.put("user_id", 1);
        values.put("description", "grocery shopping");
        long sampled = db.insert("transactions", null, values);
    }`

Comment: The array list transactions is still null though

Comment: I did a log in the databaseHelper and it's not logging; which means it isn't getting called even though I instantiated ti

Comment: Could you create a separate question as this one is solved, its too confusing what the issue is now

Comment: Might be more helpful to go through a tutorial first, by looking at your code, feels like you don't know whats going on. Go through sqlite and then asynctask, will be alot easier in the future

Comment: Hi, I was watching a tutorial, finished it, then decided to approach the project by myself to practice the skills I learned. Basically, this is just a recreation; but thanks for the feedback